# Display nested category

Tags: category

I have an entry which has a category field 'productCategory' and the chosen category is a nested one (3 deep), I want to output the category and where it's nested, but by using the field's name: `{{ entry.productCategory.one() }}` I get the parent category only, because of `.one()` I guess, if I use without `.one()`, then I get a tonne of queries displayed, so I'm not sure how to even approach displaying the actual nested category like a breadcrumb trail. I can display the categories as a nested navigation, but for now I want the entry's chosen category, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

aah

```
{% for category in entry.productCategory %}
    {{ category.title }} >
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: now to highlight the nested category!

Comment: Is there a way to make a nested category active?

Comment: the entry category field value is:

Transformers  
> Standard Fixed Installation Transformers  
> Wall/floor mounting Transformers 1-10KVA

Comment: I want make 'Wall/floor mounting Transformers 1-10KVA' active

Comment: so I need a way to dynamically detect what level the nested category is: rather than this static approach:


```<ul>
    {% nav category in entry.productCategory %}
        <li>
         {% if category.level == 1 %}
           {{ category.title }}         
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if category.level == 2 %}
        {{ category.title }}
        {% endif %}

          {% if category.level == 3 %}
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endnav %}
</ul>```